# Run 2 separate Kendo-UI Angular Projects at once (theoretically as if it was only one project)

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, port, project, differentiation

My current situation is that I've got 2 separate Angular Kendo-UI Projects. One is a Validator (Log-in) and the second one is a Grid. Those 2 Projects work fine when I start their Server separately.

[image]

BUT I want to run them at once, as I need them to work as ONE Project, which is running on the SAME port.

[image]

My Grid is accessable through a button, on the Validator website. But the Grid won't load if I don't start it separately on another port in the Angular CLI. Both of them are included in the same Folder and I want to build/prod them later but I can not move on as long as my current problem is not fixed.

I can not choose an alternative way, because I will need to work on them later and I want to have the possibility to update/fix them separately.

[image]

I have thought about to simply re-create the Grid inside of the files of the Validator, but then I can not work on them separately, because one won't work without the other...

Is their a solution, or something I don't know about? because I can't imagine that you have the abillity to create multiple projects, but you can't run them on the same server at once.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

we talk about dev servers here? I assume that they at least have different root. In that case run other server (srv2) on different port and provide proxy config for srv1 that directs app2 path to srv2